# Selenium doesnt fetch url (3 lines of python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Using chrome 76.0.3809.132 with chromedriver 76.0.3809.126 the testing browser opens but throws a traceback on the `driver.get`. It isn't able to fetch the page.

Tried couple of arguments, and tried looking for an older version of Chrome with an older chrome driver, which seems impossible.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("www.google.com")
```

Output:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57577/devtools/browser/7494ca24-60fb-4b14-9aed-4f25232b94bd

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "slidingwindow.py", line 5, in <module>
     driver.get("www.google.com")
   File "C:\projects\python\harvester\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 333, in get
     self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
   File "C:\projects\python\harvester\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute       
     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
   File "C:\projects\python\harvester\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument   (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to insert https://:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: Wauw, tried a lot, but not this, it works.. but why? it never shows up on documentation or examples.

Comment: For selenium is an invalid argument "www.google.com" but "https:// www.google.com" is valid because selenium is asking for an url

Comment: Google especially use https protocol and blocks what he thinks are bots... Using https you are giving proof to google that you're not a bot